# How to count rows?

Tags: list, r, dataframe

I have simple question (at least not for me ..). I have been ended with list with multiple dataframes of different length. I want to count length of each dataframe..

```
mylist <- list (a = data.frame(i = 1:10, j= 11:20), b = data.frame(i = 1:5, j= 11:15), c = data.frame(i = 1:8, j= 11:18))
mylist
$a
    i  j
1   1 11
2   2 12
3   3 13
4   4 14
5   5 15
6   6 16
7   7 17
8   8 18
9   9 19
10 10 20

$b
  i  j
1 1 11
2 2 12
3 3 13
4 4 14
5 5 15

$c
  i  j
1 1 11
2 2 12
3 3 13
4 4 14
5 5 15
6 6 16
7 7 17
8 8 18
```

My poor codes:

```
lapply(mylist, function(y)length(y) 

$a
[1] 2

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 2
```

Oh....no.....
How can I count number of rows in each component dataframe and get a new vector with:

```
 # number of rows in each component dataframe of the list 
 myvec
[1] 10  5  8
```

Thank you for your time...I appreciate it...

Comment: `sapply` rather than `lapply`.

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
myvec <- sapply(mylist, NROW)
```

`length` gives "odd" results with data.frames because data.frames are really lists of vectors of the same length.  `length(data.frame)` is giving you the length of the underlying list, which is the number of columns of the data.frame.

`NROW` and `NCOL` are nice because they tend to give "expected" results for most objects.  I use them a lot interactively, but fall back to `nrow`, `ncol`, and `length` when writing stable code (e.g. programs, packages) because they avoid the overhead of a few extra function calls.

Answer (score 3):

```
lengths(mylist)
```

will return the length of each element in the list. Note "lengths" (plural)

Answer (score -1):

```
    int q = list.Length;
    int f = list.GetLength(0);
    int e = list.GetLength(1);
    Console.WriteLine("length of row :" + f);
    Console.WriteLine("length of column :" + e);
    Console.WriteLine("length of components in list :" + q);
```

The overall no of components or the length of elements in an array can be found as indicated for variable 'q'. To find the no of rows in a array or list use the function GetLength() with 0 as input value and for no of rows we can use the same function with the intake value as 1.