# How to count number of rows in all dataframes that exist in R environment

Tags: r, dataframe

I have created dataframes in R environment. Now I want to count number of rows on each dataframe and store them along with their names in a separate dataframe. I have already tried

[number of rows each data frame in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609908/number-of-rows-each-data-frame-in-a-list)
and
[How to count rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340197/how-to-count-rows)

but none of these worked for me.

Comment: store all dataframes in a list: `dfrs <- list(df1, df2, df3,...)` count rows: `dfrs.nrows <- sapply(dfr, nrow)`. Otherwise you need to provide more insights into your code/data.

Answer (score 3):

We can go through all the objects in the environment with `ls()`, select only those which are of `class` "data.frame" and then create a new data frame.

```
data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(ls(), function(x) {
    obj = get(x)
   if (class(obj) == "data.frame")
     c(name = x, rows = nrow(obj))
})))

#These are the dataframes in my environment.
#         name rows
#1 complete_df   50
#2          df   50
#3        melt   24
#4      new_df   50
```

Answer (score 1):

How about below?

```
env_objs = ls();
sapply(env_objs,function(x) {
    if(class(get(x)) == "data.frame") {
      return(nrow(get(x))) 
   } 
  });
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I found another yas as well ZZ =ls()  AY=sapply(ZZ, function(x) {return(nrow(get(x)))})  earlier I was not using get(x)